# Retrieve data from AWS Cognito using Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito

I am using `AWS Cognito` to authenticate user, been successfully in storing user details like username, lastname, address etc. But unable to find any relevant methods to retrieve data stored in Cognito using `Boto3`.

Is it possible to retrieve `user` data in AWS Cognito or I should store them in RDS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by using the [`get_user`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.get_user) method.

> - **UserAttributes** (*list*) -- An array of name-value pairs representing user attributes.
>
>   For custom attributes, you must prepend the `custom:` prefix to the
>     attribute name.
>
>   - (*dict*) -- Specifies whether the attribute is standard or custom.
>
>     - **Name** (*string*) -- The name of the attribute.
>     - **Value** (*string*) -- The value of the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [list-users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/list-users.html) to list your users, but you won't be able to list all the users at once from Cognito without a third party tool since there's a limit on number of users per request. You should use [Cognito-Triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html) to store your user in an RDS or DynamoDB, if you want to be able to retrieve all your users.