# Get current User ID from associated user pool of Amazon Cognito via Python boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito

According to the [boto3 SDK docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#id114) there is a method [get_user()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.get_user) from the 'cognito-idp' - client, which was also mentioned in [this more generic scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54703889/retrieve-data-from-aws-cognito-using-boto3) of retrieving 'user data'.

Yet, **the response syntax does not seem to contain the User ID**:

> {
> '**Username**': 'string',
> 'UserAttributes': [
> {
> '**Name**': 'string',
> '**Value**': 'string'
> },
> ],
> 'MFAOptions': [
> {
> 'DeliveryMedium': 'SMS'|'EMAIL',
> 'AttributeName': 'string'
> },
> ],
> 'PreferredMfaSetting': 'string',
> 'UserMFASettingList': [
> 'string',
> ] }

Moreover, there seem to be [3 different Cognito boto3 interfaces](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/index.html):

[image: Cognito boto3 interfaces]

Thus, it is not clear to me which one I would need to use for my purpose:

In my test account, I have a Cognito user called "aws-amplify-admin" with a user ID "692a...":

[image: user name and ID in Amazon Cognito]

Down below, I see a field "User attributes" which contains as a value the very same user ID from above:

[image: User attributes with ID]

I'm wondering **which boto3-method of the Cognito client I can use** to retrieve this user ID as a string?

In case it would indeed be said [get_user()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.get_user) - method, would it then be:

```
response = client.get_user(
    AccessToken='access_token_string'
)
user_id = response['UserAttributes']['Value']
```

Answer (score 1):

As I see your user is called "aws-amplify-admin", I assume it will have admin access to the cognito user pool. In that case you can use the following [admin_get_user()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.admin_get_user) method to fetch user id.

```py
def admin_get_user_attr_data(cognito_idp_client):
    response = cognito_idp_client.admin_get_user(
        UserPoolId='<user_pool_id>', Username='<user_name>')
    pprint(response['UserAttributes'])
    return response
```

as you can see, all the user attributes are a pair of `Name` and `Value`. The `UserAttributes` contains `sub` and its value is the user id you are looking for.

```json
[{'Name': 'sub', 'Value': '<user_id>'},
 {'Name': 'email_verified', 'Value': 'false'},
 {'Name': 'email', 'Value': 'foobar@example.com'}]
```

alternatively, you can also use the non-admin [get_user()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.get_user) method to fetch the user.

```py
def get_user_attr_data(cognito_idp_client):
    response = cognito_idp_client.get_user(
        AccessToken='<access_token>')
    pprint(response['UserAttributes'])
    return response
```

It returns exactly the same response, assuming your access token of the `foobar` user.

Comment: Thanks @lipeiran, I will try that out and let you know!